# Add header to http request

Tags: javascript, android, rest, http, get

My first post here. 
I'm using droidscript and I have to include an header that contains a specific user and a password in order to retrieve a token. I'm having trouble because I don't know where to include those headers.

That's the code I'm using:

```
function btn_OnTouch(){

    var url = "myurl";
    SendRequest(url);

}

//Send an http get request.

function SendRequest(url){

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        HandleReply(httpRequest);
    };

    httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);

    httpRequest.send(null);

    app.ShowProgress("Loading...");

}

//Handle the servers reply (a json object).

function HandleReply(httpRequest){

    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4){

        //If we got a valid response.

        if (httpRequest.status == 200){
            txt.SetText("Response: " + httpRequest.status + httpRequest.responseText);
        }

        //An error occurred
        else
            txt.SetText("Error: " + httpRequest.status + httpRequest.responseText);

    }

    app.HideProgress();

}
```

The told me I should probably include the headers like this, but I don't know where to put them in my code.

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader(“username”, “myuser”);

httpRequest.setRequestHeader(“password”, “mypass”);
```

Comment: Try it before `httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);` in `SendRequest( url )`

Comment: Didn't work.It gives me this error: Script error: failed to execute "setRequestHeader" on "XMLHttpRequest": The object's state must be opened.

Comment: Well, as it says that the "object's state must be open" and obviously the headers should be set before sending the request then how about placing the code after `open()` and before `send()`.

Comment: Then it has to be after `httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);` but before `httpRequest.send(null);`

Comment: Retrieves this error: Error 0

Comment: Replace `httpRequest.send(null);` with `httpRequest.send();`

Comment: It gives me the same error..

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it just after calling the open method like this:-

```
httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("username", "myuser");
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("password", "mypass");
httpRequest.send(null);
```